# REST: Mapping 404 HTTP Status codes

Tags: web-services, rest, restlet

Our team is developing RESTFul applications...we are debating the "BEST PRACTICE" approach.

Should 404 status code response be returned for a filter-like query? Say my GET URL is

.../1/service/startsWith/a.json

and it returns all values that start with A in my database...but if no "a" values are found should i just return status code 200 with an empty json string? or status code 404.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821663/querystring-in-rest-resource-url/3822676#3822676) question, in the update to my answer I address your issue.
Specifically this bit,

> I think the answer to whether to
>   return 404 depends on the what is the
>   resource that is being retrieved. Is
>   it a representation of a search
>   result, or is it a representation of a
>   product? To know this you really need
>   to look at the link relation that led
>   us to the URL.
>
> If the URL is supposed to return a
>   Product representation then a 404
>   should be returned if the code does
>   not exist. If the URL returns a search
>   result then it shouldn't return a 404.
>
> The end result is that what the URL
>   looks like is not the determining
>   factor. Having said that, it is
>   convention that query strings are used
>   to return search results so it is more
>   intuitive to use that style of URL
>   when you don't want to return 404s.

Comment: Yea, I agree with Darrel. Simply, "no results" is a valid search result. The resource exists, it's representation is simply "empty". So, 404 is not justified. Asking for a concrete resource by an identifier (/customers/123) that does not exist warrants a 404. That's not a query, that's more a "dereference" of a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

It may be more sensible to return a 204 code, which means 'No Content'. This would be slightly more efficient as a 204 status cannot have any document content, plus you can detect the code instead of having to parse the response.