# Design RESTful URI

Tags: api, http, rest, get

I am in the process of creating a RESTful API. I read

http://microformats.org/wiki/rest/urls

but this site doesn't give me enough "good" practice on designing my API.
Specifically I will write an API (only GET methods that far) which will provide functions to convert geo-coordinates.

Example:
A geohash is a single value representation of a coordinate, thus
/convert/geohash/u09tvkx0.json?outputformat=latlong

makes sense. On the other hand
/convert/latlong.xml?lat=65&long=13&outputformat=UTC requires two input values.

See my "question"? What makes a good API which requires more than one input parameter?

(Tried to "identify" good practice by "analysing" twitter & FF but failed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of being considered a "technically" correct REST URI, there is no difference between using query string parameters or not.  In [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), it states:

> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with data in the path component (Section 3.3), serves to identify a resource

That's why you're having a difficult time finding a definitive "best practice". Having said that, many REST APIs do embed multiple parameters in the URI without using query strings.  For exammple, to identify the make *and* model of a car, you'll see websites with URI's like this: cars.com/honda/civic.  In that case it's *very* obvious the relationship between the 2 and so having everything in the URI is "hackable". It's also much easier to stick with a non-query string approach when you only have one parameter which is uniquely identifying the resource; but if it's something like a search query, then I'd probably keep it in the query string. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821663/querystring-in-rest-resource-url/3821828#3821828) has an interesting discussion about the different approaches as well.

In your example above, I would stick with the query string parameters. Although REST typically has more intuitive URLs, that's really not what REST is about. REST is more about hypermedia and [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! It filled the conceptual gap I had with REST "design principles". Wasn't aware of HATEOAS but I like the attitude.

Answer (score 0):

There are few REST best practices to be followed when designing a REST API

1. Abstract vs Concrete
2. CRUD Operations
3. Error Handling
4. API Versioning
5. Filtering
6. Security
7. Analytics
8. Documentation
9. Stability and Consistency
10. URL Structure

[Read More](http://dasunhegoda.com/rest-api-architecture-best-practices/1049/)