# RESTful API: how design URI, by query string or hierarchical?

Tags: api, rest, collections, uri

I have a "normal" web app where I list services worldwide.
There are 2 ways of listing books: 1) by using a search field or 2) using a hierarchical path design.

Example 1) Seach field generates URIs like:
mysite.com/en/services?location=london&category=lowcost

Example 2) Path like:
mysite.com/en/services/uk/london/lowcost

Both examples list the same services.

But now I have to code a RESTful API. So my question is:
Which interface/way should I offer to my api clients ? I mean, should they just request my data by using a query string (example 1) or should they build the path by their own, it means that they should know, for example that london belongs to uk :) (or chiang-mai to thailand) ...

It would be a good idea to offer both ways ?
BUt, if I offer both, is it a good RESTful API design that 2 resources (in this case colletions) target the same resource ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querystring in REST Resource url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821663/querystring-in-rest-resource-url)

Answer (score 3):

The pathname is for hierarchy, the query string for filtering.

1. If it's a supercategory of the named-object, it goes in the pathname.
2. If it uniquely identifies the named-object, it's the last component of the pathname.
3. If it's a property or sub-object of the named-object that doesn't uniquely identify the object, it goes in the query string.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your answer properly. I mean, what are you calling supercategory in this example? maybe "service" ? Is named-object a resource (in my examples both are collections)