# REST API 404: Bad URI, or Missing Resource?

Tags: web-services, http, rest

I'm building a REST API, but I've encountered a problem.

It seems that accepted practice in designing a REST API is that if the resource requested doesn't exist, a 404 is returned.

However, to me, this adds unnecessary ambiguity. HTTP 404 is more traditionally associated with a bad URI. So in effect we're saying *"Either you got to the right place, but that specific record does not exist, **or** there's no such location on the Internets! I'm really not sure which one..."*

Consider the following URI:

```
http://mywebsite/api/user/13
```

If I get a 404 back, is that because User 13 does not exist? Or is it because my URL *should* have been:

```
http://mywebsite/restapi/user/13
```

In the past, I've just returned a NULL result with an `HTTP 200 OK` response code if the record doesn't exist. It's simple, and in my opinion very clean, even if it's not necessarily accepted practice. But is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Probably a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821663/querystring-in-rest-resource-url/3822676#3822676

Comment: The other question seems to be related to URI Query string formats. The discussion on 404 there is not sufficient to answer my question, which is whether there's a more appropriate or useful way to determine what a 404 actually means. I reviewed that one before posting.

Comment: Is it normal when browser concole consist the errors 404? When i do regular operations with correct uri but resource not found.

Comment: 404 does not indicate a bad URI, it indicates a resource Not Found. That might be because there is no user '13', or it might be because there is no resource /mywebsite/api.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

404 is just the HTTP response code.  On top of that, you can provide a response body and/or other headers with a more meaningful error message that developers will see.

Comment: This makes sense. I have to wonder, though, whether any benefit is actually gained from returning the 404 in the first place, versus returning a 200 with a null response?

Comment: If you return a 200 with a null you are going against the HTTP Spec. You can do this, but then your api will not adhere to the "Uniformed Interface" Constraint of REST.

Comment: ...and your response body should include hyperlinks to valid URI's. Barring the root URI, and perhaps a bookmark or two, your clients should *always* be following links given to them by the server. Then there's no need to invent detailed semantics regarding exactly how they decided to work outside the system.

Comment: @DarrylHebbes what do you mean, I can do a request and see the complete contents of the response in the Network tab of the Chrome developer console.

Comment: It is incredibly bad to return an error (404 or whatever) for any query that returns empty results. No database will do that and usually you don't want to report an empty result as an unexpected condition to the user. Example: you query your api to check if there is an appointment scheduled for the next 30 minutes. If there is none, you should NOT return a 404. Return a 200 OK and an empty array, please.

Comment: In my case, what I would like to achieve is a clean console when there are no errors in the webapp. Unfortunately all modern browsers think that 404 is an error and shows it as such in the console and the network tab when you open the devtools. There must be some better way, I hope.

Comment: I would argue that 404 is not an error any more than `null` on its own is an error. Granted, it's not what the user was expecting, which is why browsers flag it like an error, but the server did exactly what you asked successfully. I would also posit a difference between "empty results" and "no result": empty is when you perform a search and the result is an empty list (`/obj?id=foo`->`200 OK []`), but no result is when you ask for something specific that doesn't exist (`/obj/foo`->`404 Not Found`).

Answer (score 85):

**Use `404` if the resource does not exist.  Don't return `200` with an empty body.**

**This is akin to `undefined` vs empty string (e.g. `""`) in programming.  While very similar, there is definitely a difference.**

`404` means that nothing exists at that URI (like an undefined variable in programming).  Returning `200` with an empty body means that something does exist there and that something is just empty right now (like an empty string in programming).

`404` doesn't mean it was a "bad URI".  There are special HTTP codes that are intended for  URI errors (e.g. `414 Request-URI Too Long`).

Comment: Hey, I think you might be onto something. Wouldn't it make more sense to return one of the "41?" errors when there's a problem with the requested resource? For example, **410 Gone** means *"The requested resource is no longer available at the server and no forwarding address is known."* -- (See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.11)

Comment: Actually, the resource I referenced above also says, *"If the server does not know, or has no facility to determine, whether or not the condition is permanent, the status code 404 (Not Found) SHOULD be used instead."* So maybe that isn't necessarily the best option either..

Comment: I don't think any of the 41x errors are appropriate to your use case.  I like the comparison to undefined vs. empty string, which is a more concise version of my point in my answer.  There is a difference, but that doesn't imply that an empty string is an error.  To stretch the analogy: You could have a method `String getName()` that has an implementation like this: `return this.name == null ? "" : this.name`.  That's not incorrect unless you want the client to know that `this.name` is `null`.

Comment: 404 is still the most appropriate option. You can (and are encouraged to) use the body of that 404 response to inform the user/client of specific details for receiving the error.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9999335/105484.  In your case you might want to use that body to suggest to the user that they reformat their URI to look like /restapi/user/USER_ID

Comment: Ok, I can see some good points here, but 4XX are error codes, how is that an error situation? How can client prevent 404 from happening?

Comment: Indeed, according to google 404 is an error https://www.google.com/donotexist

Comment: Generally, I think of the HTML codes as a phone call or sending a snail mail letter. If the number you dialed isn't in service, busy or blocking you, you get an error message. Now if you call a number (by mistake) and the person who answered the call doesn't speak the same language as you, should the phone have prevented the call from going through? While it would be helpful to the caller, that isn't the phone's job. So I would go with the save the HTML error codes for issues with communication and issues with the data be returned with what you would consider error data hence your blank.

Answer (score 28):

As with most things, "it depends".  But to me, your practice is not bad and is not going against the HTTP spec *per se*.  However, let's clear some things up.

First, URI's should be opaque.  Even if they're not opaque to people, they are opaque to machines.  In other words, the difference between `http://mywebsite/api/user/13`, `http://mywebsite/restapi/user/13` is the same as the difference between `http://mywebsite/api/user/13` and `http://mywebsite/api/user/14` i.e. not the same is not the same period.  So a 404 would be completely appropriate for `http://mywebsite/api/user/14` (if there is no such user) but not necessarily the only appropriate response.

You could also return an empty 200 response or more explicitly a 204 (No Content) response.  This would convey something else to the client.  It would imply that the resource identified by `http://mywebsite/api/user/14` has no content or is essentially nothing.  It does mean that there *is* such a resource.  However, it does not necessarily mean that you are claiming there is some user persisted in a data store with id 14.  That's your private concern, not the concern of the client making the request.  So, if it makes sense to model your resources that way, go ahead.

There are some security implications to giving your clients information that would make it easier for them to guess legitimate URI's.  Returning a 200 on misses instead of a 404 may give the client a clue that at least the `http://mywebsite/api/user` part is correct.  A malicious client could just keep trying different integers.  But to me, a malicious client would be able to guess the `http://mywebsite/api/user` part anyway.  A better remedy would be to use UUID's.  i.e. `http://mywebsite/api/user/3dd5b770-79ea-11e1-b0c4-0800200c9a66` is better than `http://mywebsite/api/user/14`.  Doing that, you could use your technique of returning 200's without giving much away.

Comment: This is the solution I chose and went with using a 204 instead of a 404. To me 204 means "I found your code, but didn't find results" and 404 means "I couldn't find any code to execute, is this the wrong path?"

Answer (score 16):

That is an very old post but I faced to a similar problem and I would like to share my experience with you guys.

I am building microservice architecture with rest APIs. I have some rest GET services, they collect data from back-end system based on the request parameters.

I followed the rest API design documents and I sent back HTTP 404 with a perfect JSON error message to client when there was no data which align to the query conditions (for example zero record was selected).

When there was no data to sent back to the client I prepared an perfect JSON message with internal error code, etc. to inform the client about the reason of the "Not Found" and it was sent back to the client with HTTP 404. That works fine.

Later I have created a rest API client class which is an easy helper to hide the HTTP communication related code and I used this helper all the time when I called my rest APIs from my code.

BUT I needed to write confusing extra code just because HTTP 404 had two different functions:

- the real HTTP 404 when the rest API is not available in the given url, it is thrown by the application server or web-server where the rest API application runs
- client get back HTTP 404 as well when there is no data in database based on the where condition of the query.

Important: My rest API error handler catches all the exceptions appears in the back-end service which means in case of any error my rest API always returns with a perfect JSON message with the message details.

This is the 1st version of my client helper method which handles the two different HTTP 404 response:

```
public static String getSomething(final String uuid) {
    String serviceUrl = getServiceUrl();
    String path = "user/" + , uuid);
    String requestUrl = serviceUrl + path;
    String httpMethod = "GET";

    Response response = client
            .target(serviceUrl)
            .path(path)
            .request(ExtendedMediaType.APPLICATION_UTF8)
            .get();

    if (response.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
        // HTTP 200
        return response.readEntity(String.class);
    } else {
        // confusing code comes here just because
        // I need to decide the type of HTTP 404...

        // trying to parse response body
        try {
            String responseBody = response.readEntity(String.class);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ErrorInfo errorInfo = mapper.readValue(responseBody, ErrorInfo.class);

            // re-throw the original exception
            throw new MyException(errorInfo);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // this is a real HTTP 404
            throw new ServiceUnavailableError(response, requestUrl, httpMethod);
        }

    // this exception will never be thrown
    throw new Exception("UNEXPECTED ERRORS, BETTER IF YOU DO NOT SEE IT IN THE LOG");
}
```

**BUT**, because my Java or JavaScript client can receive two kind of HTTP 404 somehow I need to check the body of the response in case of HTTP 404. If I can parse the response body then I am sure I got back a response where there was no data to send back to the client.

If I am not able to parse the response that means I got back a real HTTP 404 from the web server (not from the rest API application).

It is so confusing and the client application always needs to do extra parsing to check the real  reason of HTTP 404.

Honestly I do not like this solution. It is confusing, needs to add extra bullshit code to clients all the time.

So instead of using HTTP 404 in this two different scenarios I decided that I will do the following:

- I am not using HTTP 404 as a response HTTP code in my rest application anymore.
- I am going to use HTTP 204 (No Content) instead of HTTP 404.

In that case client code can be more elegant:

```
public static String getString(final String processId, final String key) {
    String serviceUrl = getServiceUrl();
    String path = String.format("key/%s", key);
    String requestUrl = serviceUrl + path;
    String httpMethod = "GET";

    log(requestUrl);

    Response response = client
            .target(serviceUrl)
            .path(path)
            .request(ExtendedMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .header(CustomHttpHeader.PROCESS_ID, processId)
            .get();

    if (response.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
        return response.readEntity(String.class);
    } else {
        String body = response.readEntity(String.class);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ErrorInfo errorInfo = mapper.readValue(body, ErrorInfo.class);
        throw new MyException(errorInfo);
    }

    throw new AnyServerError(response, requestUrl, httpMethod);
}
```

I think this handles that issue better.

If you have any better solution please share it with us.

Comment: Apache HttpClient methods don't throw exception on a 204 response. If your client just answers business objects (models), then that will return null. Works, but difficult for end users to detect the 204 situation.

Comment: It's all good, but a question is: how often do you write if statements for the 404? And what would it be? On the other hand, if you make a call to the api, that defines possible 404 with the error json inside, you can handle it just for this case.

Comment: zappee I agree with you.  I have a service which returns data.  But there's situations where the data is broken.  The request URL is correct (so not a 404), but it's not really a logic error (500), so 204 seems the most suitable.  It's really annoying about the lack of a message body thing.  Although arguably I could insert a reason into a Header.

Answer (score 13):

**404 Not Found** technically means that uri does not currently *map* to a resource. In your example, I interpret a request to `http://mywebsite/api/user/13` that returns a **404** to imply that this url was *never* mapped to a resource. To the client, that should be the end of conversation.

To address concerns with ambiguity, you can enhance your API by providing other response codes. For example, suppose you want to allow clients to issue GET requests the url `http://mywebsite/api/user/13`, you want to communicate that clients should use the canonical url `http://mywebsite/restapi/user/13`. In that case, you may want to consider issuing a permanent redirect by returning a *301 Moved Permanently* and supply the canonical url in the *Location* header of the response. This tells the client that for future requests they should use the canonical url.

Answer (score 12):

So in essence, it sounds like the answer could depend on how the request is formed.

If the requested resource forms part of the URI as per a request to `http://mywebsite/restapi/user/13` and user 13 does not exist, then a 404 is probably appropriate and intuitive because the URI is representative of a non-existent user/entity/document/etc. The same would hold for the more secure technique using a GUID `http://mywebsite/api/user/3dd5b770-79ea-11e1-b0c4-0800200c9a66` and the api/restapi argument above.

However, if the requested resource ID was included in the request header [include your own example], or indeed, in the URI as a parameter, eg `http://mywebsite/restapi/user/?UID=13` then the URI would still be correct (because the concept of a USER does exits at `http://mywebsite/restapi/user/`); and therefore the response could reasonable be expected to be a 200 (with an appropriately verbose message) because the specific user known as 13 does not exist but the URI does. This way we are saying the URI is good, but the request for data has no content.

Personally a 200 still doesn't feel right (though I have previously argued it does). A 200 response code (without a verbose response) could cause an issue not to be investigated when an incorrect ID is sent for example.

A better approach would be to send a `204 - No Content`response. This is compliant with w3c's description *The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation.*1 The confusion, in my opinion is caused by the Wikipedia entry stating *204 No Content - The server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content. **Usually used as a response to a successful delete request**.* The last sentence is highly debateable. Consider the situation without that sentence and the solution is easy - just send a 204 if the entity does not exist. There is even an argument for returning a 204 instead of a 404, the request has been processed and no content has been returned! Please be aware though, 204's do not allow content in the response body

Sources

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
1. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 11):

This recently came up with our team.
We use both `404 Not found` with a message body and `204 No Content` based on the following rational.

If the request URI indicates the location of a single resource, we use 404 Not found. When the request queries a URI, we use 204 No Content

- `http://mywebsite/api/user/13` would return 404 when user 13 does not exist
- `http://mywebsite/api/users?id=13` would return 204 no content
- `http://mywebsite/api/users?firstname=test` would return 204 no content

The idea here being, 'query routes' are expected to be able to return 1, many or no content.

Whatever pattern you choose, the most important things is to **be consistent** - so get buy in from your team.

Comment: What if one of your router/services is down/misbehaving and sends 404's? Will you clients assume that the resource doesn't exist and therefore allow for the creation of it? Also, i found some router circuit breaker implementations that dont go along very well with constant 404's and - after some repeated 404s - will open the circuit.

Comment: This is the pattern I have used for single hosts OR single server apis. Have never ran into routing issues as you described. Concurrency being the only real example i can think of; Where the resource was deleted by one user and another user wanted to fetch or mutate that same resource. We did hard deletes in that system, so we could not respond with 410 Gone.

Answer (score 8):

This old but excellent article... http://www.infoq.com/articles/webber-rest-workflow says this about it...

404 Not Found - The service is far too lazy (or secure) to give us a real reason why our request failed, but whatever the reason, we need to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

The Uniform Resource Identifier is a unique pointer to the resource. A poorly form URI doesn't point to the resource and therefore performing a GET on it will not return a resource. 404 means The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. If you put in the wrong URI or bad URI that is your problem and the reason you didn't get to a resource whether a HTML page or IMG.

Answer (score 0):

Since this discussion seems to be able to survive the end of time I'll throw in the [JSON:API Specifications](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-resources-responses-404)

> **404 Not Found**
> A server MUST respond with 404 Not Found when processing a request to fetch a single resource that does not exist, except when the request warrants a 200 OK response with null as the primary data (as described above).

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://example.com/articles/1/author"
  },
  "data": null
}
```

Also please see this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746894/what-is-the-proper-rest-response-code-for-a-valid-request-but-an-empty-data)

Answer (score 0):

### Paradigms

My guess to what has fueled the discussion here is that different programmers approach problems differently.

In the database paradigm selecting from a relation with a key that does not exist won't get an error but an empty result (zero tupels). Likewise if attempting to delete from a relation with no matching records. A valid request with a likewise valid response *no records affected*.

In the service realm a client might get more information and an error if a resource is non existant. It boils down to this: if a client requests a very specific url (`/user/9`) and 9 was not assigned it is just as not found as `/usr/9` the resource does not exist and should yield a 404.

If however I allow the service to find resources based on something of a wildcard an empty result is not an error situation but a clear 204 Empty Result situation. So `/user?Firstname=John` will never be a 404 if both user exist and these Things have Firstnames but a 200 or a 204. But `/user?FName=John` is a malformed and should get a 400 Bad Request (not a 404 Not Found) probably with body explaining what is going on [rfc7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807).

Carying this thought further it would mean that `/user/9` could be an 404 but `/user?ID=9` would be a 204 if user are Things and have IDs but ID 9 does not gel. This would help client development considerably as the first case clearly has a logic problem (the url was created based on for instance a list provided in another request) or a user problem (the user got hold of a user number 9 and attempts to search for it) which should get an empty result of some sort, not an error.

### TLDR;

If user is a valid target but user 9 does not exist

- `/usr/10` => 400 Bad request usr is not a Thing
- `/user/8` => 200 if a user with ID 8 exist, that is
- `/user/9` => 404 this resource does not exist
- `/user?ID=9` => 204 valid request but no results, if IDs are Thingies
- `/user?Number=9` => 400 Bad request the Thing user does not have *Number*
- `/user?ID=.gte.9` => 200 or 204 # whether users with usernr >= 9 exist

Answer (score 0):

> Consider the following URI:
>
> `http://mywebsite/api/user/13`
>
> If I get a 404 back, is that because User 13 does not exist? Or is it because my URL should have been:
>
> `http://mywebsite/restapi/user/13`

Unless you're designing with the intention that your users be manually typing out every URL, I'd say this is a non-issue. The client program shouldn't be making the user do this (unless it's `curl`), and if it does then the client developer is doing it wrong.

If the URL points to a specific resource and that resource cannot be found, 404 is the correct response.

This is different from a query, eg. `GET /user/13` vs `GET /user?id=13`. The latter should return a 200 and an empty list because it asked for all matches and there were none as opposed to asking for one specific thing that should be findable. `GET /uzer?id=13` should 404 because uzer isn't a thing that can be found.

Either way, the back-end behaved correctly and returned a correct and valid answer. If the client (*API client*, that is, i.e. a program) is hitting wrong paths, the client is misconfigured.

And, if you're doing REST and not just JSON API, then the client should have been given valid paths on `GET /` so there's no chance of a typo in the first place. With that out of the way, every reason to use something other than 404 disappears.

Answer (score -1):

For this scenario HTTP 404 is response code for the response from the REST API
Like 400, 401, 404 , 422 unprocessable entity

use the Exception handling to check the full exception message.

```
try{
  // call the rest api
} catch(RestClientException e) {
     //process exception
     if(e instanceof HttpStatusCodeException){
        String responseText=((HttpStatusCodeException)e).getResponseBodyAsString();
         //now you have the response, construct json from it, and extract the errors
         System.out.println("Exception :" +responseText);
     }

}
```

This exception block give you the proper message thrown by the REST API