# When in my REST API should I use an envelope? If I use it in one place, should I always use it?

Tags: rest

I'm working on building a RESTful web service. I have read up on the principles of using HTTP for every mechanism as far as it will take you, and most of the time, like when fetching resources, it works pretty well.

But when I need to POST a new entry of some sort, in the interest of clarity and robustness, no matter what the client may do, I want to offer the particular validation errors that the new entry may have failed at. Additionally, there are specific errors where, say, the data for creating a new user is perfectly valid, but a nickname or an email address may be taken. Simply returning `409 Conflict` doesn't finely enough detail which of the nickname or the email address was taken.

So getting around this isn't rocket science: document a bunch of specific error codes and return an object with errors:

```
{ errors: [4, 8, 42] }
```

This means that in the case of unsuccessful requests, I'm not returning the resource or its key as I may be expected to by the REST philosophy. Similarly, when I return many resources, I have to frame them in some way in an array.

So my question is: would I still be providing a well-behaved RESTful web service if I standardized an envelope to use for every request, such that, for example, there's always an object like `{ errors, isSuccessful, content }`?

I have previously built RPC-style web services that used this, but I don't want to make something that's "almost REST". If there's going to be any point to being REST, I'd want to be as well-behaved as possible.

If the answer is "hell no", which I think it may be, I would like to hear if it's at least solving the validation problem correctly, and what a good reference for this sort of problem solving might be, because most guides I've found have only detailed the simple cases.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

HTTP *is* your envelope.  You're doing the right thing by returning a 4** error code.

Having said that, there is nothing wrong with having a descriptive body on a response – in fact **in the [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4), most of the HTTP Error codes advocate that you do return a description of why the error occurred.**  See 403 for example:

> If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it **SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity.**

So you're okay to continue to use the body of a response for a more detailed description of the error(s).  If you're unsure of the specific HTTP error response to use (e.g. multiple errors), and you *know* that the user should not repeat the request as they just did it, I usually fall back to using 400.

Comment: Fair enough. What prompted me to wonder if I should use an envelope was the recurring need for detailing errors and the behavior of many REST client frameworks to only accept one kind of answer. When something can go wrong, the answer is effectively (the resource | the error | nothing), annotated with HTTP mechanisms like status codes. I'll have to make it work; maybe it'll be a lot easier if I standardize a single form of error response.

Comment: See here how Gitlab API is using the Link header for pagination https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories. Just to show you this is a best practice.

Comment: There is a big problem with that. When using a strong-typed web framework (eg Micronaut or Spring) you usually need to define a type of expected response. In case when you have a response which is sometimes `List<Foo>` and sometimes `ErrorResponse`, you have to handle it in a non-standard way. I think if we have a backend-to-backend API and both use strong-typed framework, having an envelope is more pragmatic. However, if there is an 400 then exception is thrown and we have a custom flow anyway... I'm just not 100% confident with this choice.

Answer (score 37):

Yes, an envelope can be a good idea! There's always some extra information that needs to be sent from some endpoints. Pagination, errorMessages, debugMessages for example. An example how facebook does it:

```
Response from get friends request

{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "68370", 
      "name": "Magnus"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "726497", 
      "name": "Leon"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "57034", 
      "name": "Gonçalo"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/723783051/friends?fields=id,name&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=enc_AeyGEGXHV9pJmWq2OQeWtQ2ImrJmkezZrs6z1WXXdz14Rhr2nstGCSLs0e5ErhDbJyQ"
  }, 
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 200
  }
}
```

Here we have pagination with the next link to request to get the next chunk of users and a summary with the total number of friends that can be fetched. However they don't always send this envelope, sometimes the data can go straight in the root of the body. Always sending the data the same way makes it much easier for clients to parse the data since they can do it the same for all endpoints. A small example of how clients can handle envelope responses:

```
public class Response<T> {
  public T data;
  public Paging paging;
  public Summary summary;
}

public class Paging {
  public String next;
}

public class Summary {
  public int totalCount;
}

public class WebRequest {
  public Response<List<User>> getFriends() {
    String json = FacebookApi.getFriends();
    Response<List<User>> response = Parser.parse(json);
    return response;
  }
}
```

This Response object could then be used for all endpoints by just changing List to the data that the endpoints returns.

Comment: This example is not RESTful. Meta data goes in headers. By including summary data with detail data you are dual purposing a single endpoint. You need to consider the entire systems architecture when designing an API. Caching would be problematic with this design. http://restcookbook.com/

Comment: @user1042361 can you please link the exact page you are citing that please? I can see no mention of it

Comment: HTTP is the enveloppe, no need to wrap it in another enveloppe

Comment: I've been starting to view pagination as YAGNI; it seems like a good idea at design time but is never needed since most users will search instead of paging through the data. Pagination is the only compelling use case to keep an envelope and so I've been dropping it entirely.

Comment: Hell no, HTTP is the envelop. Don't pollute the body data with meta data.  Instead, put this metadata where it belongs, in the HTTP response headers. Eg. for Pagination use the Link header.

Answer (score 3):

I think like many specific cases in REST it's up to you. I look to the web to for examples. For example when you go to a web page or URL that doesn't exist in the WWW you normally get a 404 and an HTML page that page usually has hypermedia to some resource. This hypermedia is what the service thinks you are trying to get to or may be the a home page {bookmark url}. In machine to machine REST senarios may not be using HTML as the media type, but you can still return a resource that 1) provides details on the error and 2) provides hypermedia to a valid resource

The 409 is an error code that you don't see much of in the wild WWW therefore you are kind of on your own. I use the 404 as a parallel and return a resource of errors like you are doing and also hypermedia to the resource that caused the 409 in the first place. That way if they intended to create the thing that caused the conflict in the first place they can just get it.

We did standardize on what error resources would look like so that clients would know how to consume the error. This of course is documented by following the rel in the resource.

In your specific case of "nickname or an email address" I could see using a 400 or a 409 because that is just one piece of information of the resource.

Also we don't have 1 single envelope. We use  http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html and the resource is either what they asked for or an error.

HTH

Comment: First, thanks. The example I gave was of creating a user. The username and email address could both be perfectly correct but already be occupied by other users, and it's important that the app can highlight which of the two so that the request can be corrected. That was my rationale for why picking the correct HTTP status code was helpful but not always precise enough.

Comment: Additionally, maybe it's helpful detailing that this is being used as solely a web service with no plans to serve web representations of the resources.

Comment: I assumed that it was machine to machine communication via HTTP. You still have representations of the resource. JSON or XML or .JPG or what ever. I was using the a general meaning of representation much like 'Representational State Transfer'. I agree the code is not enough, you should provide details somehow.

Answer (score 2):

If by "I standardized an envelope to use for every request" you literally mean every request, not just the one you described, I would say don't do it. In REST we try to use HTTP juts like the Web uses it, not to built an entire new proprietary protocol on top of it like SOAP. This approach keeps REST simple and easy to use. If you are interested, I've put more related thoughts here:

http://theamiableapi.com/2012/03/04/rest-and-the-art-of-protocol-design/

This being said, it is OK to return detailed error description with a HTTP error code. You first instinct, returning 409 and additional error codes sounds pretty good to me. The reason 409 is better than the generic 400 is that the error handling path in client code is cleaner. Some unrelated errors can cause 400, so if you use 400, you will need to check if there is an entity body returned, what format is it in, etc.

Comment: Very helpful, but I thought it was clear that I didn't intend for this API to turn into SOAP. I just needed to deal with a real problem, which is that of handling disparate responses (success and failure) to the same requests. I don't think defining this or wanting to be able to handle edge cases in a good way turns into building a proprietary protocol any more than working with any RESTful service within the context of its use is using a proprietary protocol. The reason I posted this question was because I was butting up against the wall of the guidance, not because I wanted to avoid it.

Comment: I really don't care what is pure "REST", as we use what we need to get the job done and supply what our integrators need, so we have to take a "pragmatic" approach. Pure is too restrictive in some real world cases where there are other moving parts besides the REST interface. We always wrap in an envelope and on more than one occasion we have found the requirement to add another field. If we did not have the envelope, we would have been trapped. Others may not find this need, so in there case, great, but on our case we need the freedom to expand.

Answer (score 0):

I used to resist the idea of enveloping the response due to the overhead of requireing to encapsulate each WebApi action.

Then I [stumbled upon this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/wrapping-asp.net-web-api-responses-for-consistency-and-to-provide-additional-information) which does it in neat way that doesnt require any extra effort and it just works

## Handler

```
public class WrappingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        return BuildApiResponse(request, response);
    }

    private static HttpResponseMessage BuildApiResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        object content;
        string errorMessage = null;

        if (response.TryGetContentValue(out content) && !response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            HttpError error = content as HttpError;

            if (error != null)
            {
                content = null;
                errorMessage = error.Message;

#if DEBUG
                errorMessage = string.Concat(errorMessage, error.ExceptionMessage, error.StackTrace);
#endif
            }
        }

        var newResponse = request.CreateResponse(response.StatusCode, new ApiResponse(response.StatusCode, content, errorMessage));

        foreach (var header in response.Headers)
        {
            newResponse.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
        }

        return newResponse;
    }
}
```

## Envelope

Custom wrapper class
[DataContract]

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Version { get { return "1.2.3"; } }

    [DataMember]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public object Result { get; set; }

    public ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode statusCode, object result = null, string errorMessage = null)
    {
        StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
        Result = result;
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

## Register it!

in WebApiConfig.cs in App_Start

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new WrappingHandler());
```