# Future proof: Is removing a JSON envelope the current best practice?

Tags: json, rest, solid-principles

I have read conflicting "opinions" on whether or not you should remove the envelope on a JSON request or reply.

Example:

```
{
    "data": {
        "foo" : "bar",
        "baz" : "Xyzzy"
    }
}
```

Should (supposedly) be written as:

```
{
    "foo" : "bar",
    "baz" : "Xyzzy"
}
```

But, in keeping with SOLID principles, this structure should be open for extension, but closed for modification. Thus, removing the envelope would be a bad idea. Right?

If, later, I decide I need to add some more information to the inbound JSON information, it is much cleaner to do this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "foo" : "bar",
        "baz" : "Xyzzy"
    },

    "extended-data": {
        "abc" : 123
    }
}
```

Than it would be to do this:

```
{
    "foo" : "bar",
    "baz" : "Xyzzy",
    "abc" : 1234
}
```

The former allows previously written code, which looks for the "data" node to execute without failures or changes. The latter requires that code be re-written to look for that new value.

What's the current best practice, and please *site your sources*: I need accepted standards not opinions.

Update:

To answer the objection: "If you add fields you have to change your code."

Not really. I don't have to change the code to handle new fields, I only have to add a new handler for new data:

Example:

```
function delegateTask($json) {
    $this->doSomething($json->data);
}
```

after extension:

```
function delegateTask($json) {
    $this->doSomething($json->data);
    $this->doSomethingElse($json->extended);
}
```

If I only use HTTP as the envelope, I have to re-write doSomething(). If I do it the SOLID way, I only need to add a function that looks at the new data.

*Not duplicate:*
This question is not a duplicate of  [When in my REST API should I use an envelope? If I use it in one place, should I always use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989135/when-in-my-rest-api-should-i-use-an-envelope-if-i-use-it-in-one-place-should-i) because this question specifically deals with S.O.L.I.D principles and extension for code as it relates to an envelope. Not just error messages being returned to a client.

Comment: Whether you use an envelope or not, you still have to change code to handle new fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When in my REST API should I use an envelope? If I use it in one place, should I always use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989135/when-in-my-rest-api-should-i-use-an-envelope-if-i-use-it-in-one-place-should-i)

Comment: I saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989135/when-in-my-rest-api-should-i-use-an-envelope-if-i-use-it-in-one-place-should-i. It's similar, but not the same. Yes, HTTP "is the envelope", but I am specifically asking this in reference to SOLID principles.

Comment: This is more of a data-model thing, isn't it? I'm not sure how SOLID principles translate to your datamodel -> either that value is supposed to be in there or not. You wouldn't change your database structure either and add a different table for instance, just so your code wouldn't have to change the same way. The same thing applies here, doesn't it?

Comment: I would hope the datamodel would not have to change, but it's possible if we were receiving entirely new data that was not in the original spec. My question pertains to existing data, those tables, and the code that would deal with them. Once it works, I don't want to have to change it to accept new data. I only want to create new handlers and (if necessary) new tables. Similar to the Factory pattern. Yes, you have to add a case to a switch() statement for a factory pattern, but you don't have to change any of the existing classes. You create (extend) new ones.

Comment: In my experience, envelopes are a better practice, but not in the way you've used them. I use envelopes to separate concerns and model data. I don't want metadata (paging, filtering) to collide with my data result schema so I put them in different envelopes. However, as far as extension, consider a "Customer" entity, I would not use "extended-data" envelope to avoid changing "handleCustomer(), down that path lies a house of cards. I would simply publish a v2 API and maintain the old one until it is deprecated. Multi-versioning of APIs is common practice (Examples: eBay, Salesforce).

Comment: Data models always change, unfortunately. When schema changes, tables change and APIs change. I think its most common to approach your API JSON schema modelling in synch with your database schema model.

Comment: My example is poor, and yours is better. I was trying to illustrate the same thing: using the envelope like a namespace. Of course we do API versioning, and yes, a significant change to how data is handled would certainly precipitate an API version update and change.

Comment: In thinking about an envelope as a namespace to separate concerns, it begs the question: why would I be issuing multiple concerns in a single response? I would not issue a response from /api/v1/Customers that included an Invoice entity, would I? However, because entities belong to customers, it's possible I might return a Customer entity when returning invoice information from /api/v1/Customers/1234/invoices...

Answer (score 6):

Envelopes are namespaces. Namespaces are a good tool for modular design and separation of concerns.

Consider the types of things you use to consume JSON APIs. Grids, etc. Separating actual data from paging and other metadata is less fragile.

I think you can apply the "I" in SOLID to this.

Interface segregation principle - “many client-specific interfaces are better than one general-purpose interface.

With an envelope, I can take any API schema and combine it with any Javascript component I choose, without worry of collisions or having to rename fields to get things to work.

The same applies to API aggregation. I can combine 2 separate results in a single call to provide a "view model" that is most efficient for a particular use. Easier to aggregate with envelopes.

Look to standards like [OData 2.0 json-format](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/json-format/) ([OData Json 4.01](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.01/odata-json-format-v4.01.html)), a lot of smart people behind that standard.

As far as extensions and life cycle, I would simply publish a v2 API and maintain the old one until it is deprecated. Multi-versioning of APIs is common practice (Examples: eBay, Salesforce).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this is really about message processing, and not specific to JSON, REST, etc.

> The former allows previously written code, which looks for the "data" node to execute without failures or changes. The latter requires that code be re-written to look for that new value.
>
> What's the current best practice, and please site your sources: I need accepted standards not opinions.

The best reference I know of is [Versioning in an Event Sourced System](https://leanpub.com/esversioning), by Greg Young.

In short

- Consumers always prepare a default value for any data that they expect to read from the message, to cover the case where the data wasn't provided
- Consumers ignore data that they do not understand
- Data offered by the provider supersedes the default provided by the consumer
- *The semantics of the data never change* ; instead, you remove the old meaning from the schema (consumers depending on it will fall back to their default understanding) and add a new meaning (which existing consumers will ignore).

There's also Oracle's reference on [schema evolution](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/NOSQL/html/GettingStartedGuide/schemaevolution.html#changeschema-rules), which describes "modifications you can safely perform to your schema without any concerns."  It references these same rules.

Avro has details [schema migration rules](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/spec.html#Schema+Resolution), which describe how a producer's schema and a consumer's schema are resolved.  Same basic idea, with more specifics about changing data types.

[RFC 4287](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-6.3) describes the "must ignore foreign markup" requirements in Atom Syndication.  [Versioning XML Vocabularies](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/12/03/versioning.html) includes a good discussion of Must Ignore.

Notice that what we are really talking about is a processing model, as [David Megginson points out](https://quoderat.megginson.com/2005/11/16/must-ignore-and-must-understand/).  The compatibility guarantees are a consequence of having the right processing model in place.

> whether or not you should remove the envelope

The envelope looks like a waste of time to me.  There's no useful difference between adding a field whose value is state, and adding a new field that holds a record to state.

```
message.get('foo').orElse('baz')

message.get('data').get('foo').orElse('baz')
```

Sorry, I can't tell the difference.  Looks like bike shedding.

*But* if you replace the generic envelopes with records that have semantic significance, and use a processing model that understands that it might not understand all the parts of the message, then that's very powerful (regardless of whether you use top level fields or records).

Also, be aware that if you are in the middle of a pipeline, "must ignore" means ignore, not *throw away* -- you need to pass the entire message to the next stage in the pipeline, and allow it to decide for itself what processing rules to apply.

> So, my take away from your comment is this: if the envelope provides semantic significance, it's fine. Can you give an example?

So, from my perspective, there's no good reason to prefer any of the following

```
get[xyzzy]
get[data][xyzzy]
get[data/xyzzy]
```

Because "data", in either spelling, doesn't tell the processing engine anything useful.

On the other hand, breaking out the message into separate logical parts that consumers may care about is interesting.  Consider the event HTTPRequestReceived -- what might a message like that look like?  Clearly, we have a concern about the event itself (so that observers can evaluate their interest in the message), and the data about what was logged), the data, maybe an evaluation of whether it is human or bot traffic, the source of the event....

```
{ event : { type : HttpRequestReceived }
, source : { logFile : ..., position : ... }
, rawData : [ ... ]
, botAnalysis : { ... }
}
```

> I could just as easily use the URI as the namespace.

You could.  A sexy variation is to use as your keys an identifier that can be used to look up the schema definition

```
{ http://example.org/event : 
    { http://example.org/event/type : HttpRequestReceived }
....
```

Schema.org has a vocabulary of common concepts that are intended for re-use

```
{ http://schema.org/dateCreated : 2017-02-13 }
```

Comment: So, my take away from your comment is this: if the envelope provides semantic significance, it's fine. Can you give an example? I have a hard time thinking of one that I would not just refactor into a different service. I am starting to lean towards removing the envelope; however, I just don't want to cut myself off at the knees by engineering a solution that precludes this form of data transport. I like the "envelope as a namespace" concept; however, I could just as easily use the URI as the namespace. Thoughts?