# What are 'envelope' objects used for?

Tags: c#, cqrs

Looking at the code for [RealWorld example apps](https://github.com/gothinkster/aspnetcore-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/Conduit/Features/Users/User.cs), I see they wrap objects in "Envelope" objects like this:

```
namespace Conduit.Features.Users
{
    public class User
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Bio { get; set; }

        public string Image { get; set; }

        public string Token { get; set; }
    }


    public class UserEnvelope
    {
        public UserEnvelope(User user)
        {
            User = user;
        }

        public User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Why is this needed? Is this part of the CQRS pattern? If so, why not just add the properties directly on the Command or Query objects or return just the `User` object by itself? If not, what is the name of this pattern?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When in my REST API should I use an envelope? If I use it in one place, should I always use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989135/when-in-my-rest-api-should-i-use-an-envelope-if-i-use-it-in-one-place-should-i)

Comment: @Igor, thanks, that link helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When in my REST API should I use an envelope? If I use it in one place, should I always use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989135/when-in-my-rest-api-should-i-use-an-envelope-if-i-use-it-in-one-place-should-i)

Comment: @TylerH technically I don't think it's a duplicate since I'm asking what they are and they are asking under what condition they should be used.

Comment: @adam0101 A fair concern; in some cases I would not have suggested it as a dupe of that, but the litany of answers there, many of which discuss their point/use cases that you've asked about here, is what made me lean toward that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can pass metadata without cluttering up the business entity.

Comment: That's what I thought, but they don't pass any metadata, so I wasn't sure if there was another reason or if it was a recommended pattern of CQRS or something. Is there a name for this pattern so I can learn more about it?