# Response Envelope for Quarkus Restful Service

Tags: jax-rs, quarkus, resteasy

I would like to define custom response envelope on Quarkus based Restful API service which I can easily configure it on Spring Framework by extending ResponseBodyAdvice and defining it with @RestControllerAdvice. Which I would like to create is very similar explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25930584/2894642

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ResponseBinder implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

    private static final String[] IGNORED_URIS = {"swagger", "v2/api-docs", "v3/api-docs", "actuator"};

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType,
                                  Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse httpResponse) {
        if (StringUtils.containsAny(request.getURI().getPath(), IGNORED_URIS)
                || body instanceof Response) {
            return body;
        } else if (body instanceof Page) {
            Page<?> page = (Page<?>) body;
            return ResponseUtil.buildWithMeta(page);
        } else if (body instanceof String) {
            return JsonUtils.serialize(ResponseUtil.build(body));
        } else {
            return ResponseUtil.build(body);
        }
    }
}
```

Using [ExceptionMapper](https://stackoverflow.com) only solves catching Throwable and returning ErrorResponse for them but I do need to handle successful cases too.

How can I do that in Quarkus?

Comment: How do you achieve that in Spring with ResponseBodyAdvice?

Comment: @geoand  I have updated question by adding sample code. You can checkout from there.

Comment: Have you had a look at  JAX-RS `WriterInterceptor`?