# Return Ok with empty list VS. No content

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, restangular

I wrote a web API that returns 204 (No Content) when a client requests all elements on a collection but the collection is empty.

For example: `/api/products` returns 204 when there are no products.

Now my problem is that I'm trying to consume the API using Restangular like this:

```
Restangular.all('products').getList().then(function (products) {
    $scope.products = products;
});
```

However this results in the following javascript error.

> Error: Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or
>   something else

What gives? I can't find any information on handling no content in the [Restangular doc](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)

Am I using 204 wrong? Should I instead return 200 with an empty list?

Comment: afaik 204 is only used when your resource never returns anything

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The 204 is apparently being treated as "no list" or null, rather than as an empty list. I'd say that's a reasonable behaviour. You're probably going to need to either check for a 204 and special-case it or change the API to return 200 OK with no elements. I would urge you to do the latter. I'm not sure that you're using 204 the way it's intended.

From [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.3),

> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
> entity-body

In your case, the server *does* need to return an entity-body, it just happens that the entity is an empty collection. Typically 204 is used for POSTs or DELETEs.

Comment: seem that 204 is not a proper in this case. As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204, the  note says 'The protocol allows user agents to vary in how they process such responses' which i assume means we should not rely on it unless you actually don't send any data not even empty array ([]).
I suggest 200 OK with  additional header to indicate no elements to make paging  easier

Comment: Though this is a very old post, 200 Ok suits the scenario when the table is empty as recommended in this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366730/proper-rest-response-for-empty-table.