# HTTP status code for a REST search without result

Tags: json, rest, http, api-design

I have a REST endpoint for a search.

`GET /person?firstname=john&name=smith`

As result a collection with the HTTP status code `200 OK` is returned:

```
[
   {
      "id":11,
      "firstname":"John",
      "name":"Smith",
      "birthday":"1996-03-08"
   },
   {
      "id":18,
      "firstname":"John",
      "name":"Smith",
      "birthday":"1963-07-11"
   }
]
```

**What is the correct HTTP status code and payload for a empty search result?**

- HTTP Status `200 OK` with a empty collection `[]`
- HTTP Status `204 No Content` with a empty collection `[]`
- HTTP Status `204 No Content` with a empty body

Comment: I'd suggest 200 because an empty list or a list with items is really the same thing, one is just a special case. Also 204 means literally no content at all while "[]" is still some content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP 200 or 404 for empty list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217761/http-200-or-404-for-empty-list)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366730/proper-rest-response-for-empty-table, and so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
HTTP Status 200 OK with a empty collection []
```

The reason is that 204 means there is no content to send back and that is not what the result of your call is.

In your case, there IS something to send back. It's a Json result that happens to be composed of an empty collection.

**UPDATE:**

From the HTTP protocol definition:

> 10.2.5 204 No Content: The server has fulfilled the request but does
>   not need to return an entity-body, and might want to return updated
>   metainformation.

And:

> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

Comment: _"no more content"_ - citation required.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I added the relevant paragraphs.

Comment: That doesn't say that 204 means _no more_ content.

Comment: Which is why I updated the answer too, if you notice.

Answer (score 4):

IMO the first case:

- HTTP Status `200 OK` with a empty collection `[]`

Then you don't have to check for the 204 and use what is returned, which is an empty list.

Comment: You beat me to it =)  Your search yielded no matching results, but you can still treat the result the same as if something did in fact match.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of convention here when you are designing your web application. **200 ok with an Empty collection** would be my way to go . Because :

- It proved that your API does return response
- Handling 200  would be much easier on client-side , as I may assume you are working with Javascript , where other response code might throw you an error