# Django Rest Framework: turn on pagination on a ViewSet (like ModelViewSet pagination)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a ViewSet like this one to list users' data:

```
class Foo(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I want to turn on pagination like the default pagination for ModelViewSet:

```
{
    "count": 55,
    "next": "http://myUrl/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [{...},{...},...,{...}]
}
```

[The official doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) says:

> Pagination is only performed automatically if you're using the generic views or viewsets

...but my resultset is not paginated at all. How can I paginate it?

Comment: Here is a very [simple answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65301286/13168560) from a similar Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> Pagination is only performed automatically if you're using the generic
>   views or viewsets

The first roadblock is translating the docs to english. What they intended to convey is that you desire a generic viewset. The generic viewsets extend from [generic ApiViews](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py) which have extra class methods for paginating querysets and responses.

Additionally,  you're providing your own `list` method, but the default pagination process is actually handled by the [mixin](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L35):

```
class ListModelMixin(object):
    """
    List a queryset.
    """
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The easy solution, use the framework code:

```
class Foo(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer
```

The more complex solution would be if you need a custom `list` method, then you should write it as you see fit but in the style of the above mixin code snippet.

Answer (score 94):

For those using DRF 3.1 or higher, they are changing the default way pagination is handled.  See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.1-announcement/ for details.

Now if you want to enable pagination for a ModelViewSet you can either do it globally by setting in your settings.py file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

Or if you just want it for one ModelViewSet you can manually set the pagination_class for just that viewset.

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
```

This also allows you to tweak the way the pagination is handled for just that viewset.

DRF 3.1 also has introduced new types of default pagination schemes that you can use such as LimitOffset and Cursor.

Comment: If you ask for page1 using PageNumberPagination, and after that a new item is added to the list, and you then ask for page2, the last item you just got in page1 will be shown again as the first item in page2 (shown 2 times in a row). CursorPagination is a much more recommended way than PageNumberPagination. CursorPagination keeps reference to objects, and does not have to calculate content for each page. For implementation see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47657610/5881884

Answer (score 8):

Try providing a class variable

```
paginate_by = 10 #This will paginate by 10 results per page.
```

Create a Custom `ViewSet` which performs only `list` operation as your case for here currently.

```
class ListModelViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    pass
```

Now inherit your class `Foo` with this custom made viewset

```
class Foo(ListModelViewSet):

    paginate_by = 10

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This should help you get the pagination working.

Comment: I added `paginate_by = 10` but It does not work. If I change `class Foo(viewsets.ViewSet):` with `class Foo(generics.ListCreateAPIView):` I get this error: _as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)_

Comment: are you passing any argument to .as_view()? Secondly why are you not using `ModelViewSet`?

Comment: No, nothing to .as_views(). I'm not using `ModelViewSet` because I need to code some logic to filter a subset of my `queryset` and to add some data to resultset not related to User model (that logic is omitted in the code of my question)

Comment: Check this link : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#custom-viewset-base-classes

Comment: Still not working :( P.S.: why did you use `MongoGenericViewSet`? I used `viewsets.GenericViewSet` instead...

Comment: I am sorry actually my project involved `mongo` hence I told to import `MongoGenericViewSet`. You can rather try `viewsets.GenericViewSet`

Comment: I tried it yesterday and I don't remember exactly what was the problem. I am quite new to Python and to DRF, hence I do not exclude that I made mistakes while testing your solution...I solved with `class Foo(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):`.

Answer (score 8):

This way also worked in Django Rest apiViews Api's

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
class FooList(APIView):

    page_size = 10

    def get(self, request):
        foo = Foo.objects.all()
        paginator = PageNumberPagination()
        paginator.page_size = page_size
        result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(foo, request)
        serializer = FooSerializer(result_page, many=True)
        return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 4):

Pagination in **DRF** using `viewsets` and `list`.

Here I have handled a exception If **page** is **empty** it will show **empty** records.

In setting define the page size, this page size is **global** and it is used by `paginator_queryset` in view.

> REST_FRAMEWORK = { 'PAGE_SIZE': 10, }

In **view.py**:

```
from rest_framework import mixins, viewsets

class SittingViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
    mixins.ListModelMixin):

    serializer_class = SittingSerializer
    queryset = Sitting.objects.all()
    serializer = serializer_class(queryset, many=True)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset =self.filter_queryset(Sitting.objects.all().order_by('id'))

        page = request.GET.get('page')

        try: 
            page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        except Exception as e:
            page = []
            data = page
            return Response({
                "status": status.HTTP_200_OK,
                "message": 'No more record.',
                "data" : data
                })

        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            data = serializer.data
            return self.get_paginated_response(data)

        # serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response({
            "status": status.HTTP_200_OK,
            "message": 'Sitting records.',
            "data" : data
        })
```

**Note**: If you not use `Order_by` it will show `exception` because this list
gives unordered list.

Comment: YOU can also visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/46173281/8231158  I have give two answer one foe Viewset and other is for API view.

Comment: queryset = Sitting.objects.all() , isn't it wrong to get all the records and then paginate based on it? What if there are millions of records, wouldn't it impact performance?

Comment: Sitting.objects.all() this was a example @Sandhu as per your requirement you can filter the record, you can write your own query as per your requirement

Comment: You should return `200 OK` with an empty list because both URL and collection do exist in the service but none matched the query arguments.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366730

Answer (score 4):

A slightly simpler variation on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34888758/903928) if you want pagination for a particular `ViewSet`, but don't need to customize the page size:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}

class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
```

Answer (score 2):

Custom Pagination using GenericAPIView
1.view.py file

```
class ModelView(GenericAPIView):
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        example_data = data.get('comment_id')
        replies = ExampleModel.objects.filter(model_field=example_data).order_by('-id')
        if replies.exists():
            replies = self.paginate_queryset(replies)
            replies = self.get_paginated_response(replies)
            return replies
        else:
            return Response({'message': 'This is the reply message!'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

2.pagination.py file

```
class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'links': {
                'next': self.page.next_page_number() if self.page.has_next() else None,
                'previous': self.page.previous_page_number() if self.page.has_previous() else None
            },
            'total': self.page.paginator.count,
            'page': int(self.request.GET.get('page', 1)), 
            'page_size': int(self.request.GET.get('page_size', self.page_size)),
            'results': ModelSerializer(data, context={'request':self.request}, many=True).data
        }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

3.my_serializer.py file

```
class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        request = self.context.get('request')
        if instance.user_information.image else None
            ret['user_name'] = instance.user_information.name
 
        return ret
```

It's all that you need.