# Pagination not working in DRF APIView

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I am using `APIView` for get and post items.
 
I wanted to implement pagination for my API using Django Rest Framework, but it is not working.

I want to show 10 items per page but when I do `api/v1/items?page=1`, I get all the items and if I just do `api/v1/items` I get an empty list.

Here is what I have done:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

class ItemsAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """
        Return a list of all items of this user.
        """
        reply = {}
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        print ('page is', page)
        try:
            products = BaseItem.objects.owned_items().filter(owner=request.user)
            reply['data'] = OwnedItemSerializer(products, many=True).data

            items = BaseItem.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
            paginator = Paginator(items, 1)
            items_with_pagination = paginator.page(page)
            if page is not None:
                reply['data'].extend(ItemSerializer(items_with_pagination, many=True).data)
            reply['data'].extend(ItemSerializer(items, many=True).data)
```

Comment: Hey, @pythonBeginner I was wondering, did you find any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 9):

Non generic views and viewsets [**do not have pagination by default**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) as stated in the django rest framework documentation:

> Pagination is only performed automatically if you're using the generic views or viewsets. If you're using a regular `APIView`, you'll need to call into the pagination API yourself to ensure you return a paginated response. See the source code for the `mixins.ListModelMixin` and `generics.GenericAPIView` classes for an example.

I have composed a [full example on enabling pagination on non generic views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670648/how-to-use-pagination-in-a-non-generic-view-viewset) with code on how to achieve this:

```
class ItemsAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    pagination_class = api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS
    serializer_class = MyNewUnifiedSerializerClass

    def get(self, request):
        user_items =  BaseItem.objects.filter(
                          owner=request.user
                      ).distinct()
        page = self.paginate_queryset(user_items)

        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.serializer_class(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(user_items, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    # Now add the pagination handlers taken from 
    #  django-rest-framework/rest_framework/generics.py

    @property
    def paginator(self):
        """
        The paginator instance associated with the view, or `None`.
        """
        if not hasattr(self, '_paginator'):
            if self.pagination_class is None:
                self._paginator = None
            else:
                self._paginator = self.pagination_class()
            return self._paginator

     def paginate_queryset(self, queryset):
         """
         Return a single page of results, 
         or `None` if pagination is disabled.
         """
         if self.paginator is None:
             return None
         return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(
                    queryset, 
                    self.request, 
                    view=self
                )

     def get_paginated_response(self, data):
         """
         Return a paginated style `Response` object 
         for the given output data.
         """
         assert self.paginator is not None
         return self.paginator.get_paginated_response(data)
```

For more details have a look at the [example link provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670648/how-to-use-pagination-in-a-non-generic-view-viewset).

Answer (score 0):

extend `GenericAPIView` instead of `APIView`
and define `pagination_class` in `GenericAPIView`

Answer (score -1):

You could make your life a lot easier and just use a ListView. By overriding render_to_response you can make it output json instead of HTML. It does all the pagination for you.

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.views.generic import ListView

class MyListView(JSONResponseMixin, ListView):
    model = models.BaseItem    
    paginate_by = 10  

    def render_to_response(self, context):
        return JsonResponse(
            serializers.serialize("json", context),
            **response_kwargs
        )
```

Comment: I have two serializers used in my APIView and an extend function as well. It is done differently. If its just using model.objects.all(), i would have preferred ListView.

Comment: Then just add whatever else you need in `get_context_data(self, **kwargs):`

Answer (score -3):

**paginator = None** worked for me

```
> class NotesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):    
>     queryset = Notes.objects.all()
>     serializer_class = NotesWriteSerializer
>     paginator = None
```

Comment: The question is asking about the `APIView` which this example doesn't address.