# Django Rest Framework pagination on GenericViewSet

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I have the following GenericViewSet, I am trying to achieve pagination for the viewset, This is my viewset

```
class UserAccountViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                      mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                      mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                      mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    queryset = UserAccount.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'username'
    lookup_url_kwarg = "username"
    serializer_class = UserAccountSerializer
    page_size = 25
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.queryset
        if request.GET.dict():
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_501_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)

        serializer = UserListSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, **kwargs):
        pass

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

this is my configuration,

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '100/day',
        'user': '100/day'
    }
}
```

It is not getting paginated, how can I make pagination work with DRF?

thank you.

Comment: Why are you overriding the `list`, `retrieve` etc functions with just a pass statement? Instead you should just be using `ModelViewSet` in place of `GenericViewSet` without all those functions.

Comment: Please look into below link, it can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785966/django-rest-framework-turn-on-pagination-on-a-viewset-like-modelviewset-pagina

Comment: @Deena Please add the code of your `list` method.

Comment: What you are trying to check using `request.GET.dict()`?

Comment: The DRF code responsible for pagination is not being called. You should instead call `super()` after that line.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are overriding `list()` method and not returning a paginated response, you are not getting paginated response in your API. Instead, **you should call `super()` in `list()` method** as DRF's `list()` method itself returns a paginated response for generic views or viewsets.

> Pagination is only **performed automatically if you're using the generic
>   views or viewsets**. If you're **using a regular `APIView`, you'll need to
>   call into the pagination API yourself** to ensure you return a paginated
>   response.

```
class UserAccountViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                      mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                      mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                      mixins.DestroyModelMixin):

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.GET.dict():
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_501_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)

        # call 'super()' to get the paginated response
        return super(UserAccountViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: it raises `'super' object has no attribute 'list'`

Comment: You should add `mixins.ListModelMixin` to `UserAccountViewSet` though i would suggest using `ModelViewSet` instead of all the mixins and `GenericViewSet`.

Comment: Have specific reasons to go with GenericViewSet.

Comment: @Deena Okay. Then you should add `mixins.ListModelMixin` to `UserAccountViewSet`.