# Creating a pagination using Django

Tags: django

I'm working on a small project using **Django Rest Framework** and i'm looking for a way to create pagination using **Viewset**, i checked the **DJR** documentation but i couldn't find any answer about doing pagination with **Viewsit class**,

this is my code :

```
class ContactView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    
    def list(self, request):
        contactObject = Contact.objects.all()
        contactSerializer = ContactSerializer(contactObject, many=True)
        return Response(contactSerializer.data)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Rest Framework: turn on pagination on a ViewSet (like ModelViewSet pagination)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785966/django-rest-framework-turn-on-pagination-on-a-viewset-like-modelviewset-pagina)

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/31789223/5600452

Comment: @c.grey   i already saw this answer but  i still need a help by an example please :)

Comment: what issue are you facing ???

Comment: i didn't understand the code i'm new in DJR,  can you give me an example using my code please, i will really appreciate

Comment: what should i import ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
class ListModelMixin(object):
    """
    List a queryset.
    """
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


class ContactView(ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer = ContactSerializer
```

Comment: 'ContactView' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method.

Comment: @AmineBouhaddi what do you mean exactly.  Not getting

Comment: fixed by adding _class thank you so much,   i can't see the pagination number :(

Comment: the code work fine, but i don't get pagination number should i do any configuration before ?

Comment: Thank you so much that's work really fine now, i have added the REST_FRAMEWORK PAGINATION in settings.py

Comment: can i send get request to my list method ?