# httpclient response is null when API returns a 204 status code

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have a rest endpoint `/Products/latest` which returns 204 in case there are no products, and the following generic angular service:

```
  getFromAPI(url: string) {
    const params = new HttpParams();

    return this.http
        .get(url, { params: params })
        .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.error(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);                  
            return Observable.of([]);
        });
  }
```

and

```
 getFromAPI() {
        return this.masterService.get('/Products/latest').map((res: Response) => {
            if (res.status === 204) {
                return Observable.of([]);
            } else {
                return res;
            }

        });
    }
```

However, when the servies results a 204 code, I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of null

How can this be happening? Why is the whole response null if the API responds with a 204?

Comment: try it in the catch method

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, I would say it is [strange (or wrong)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13366730/2477619) that your backend is returning a 204 for an empty collection instead of a 200 together with an empty list.

Using Angular7 and RxJS6 I constructed a test case where my backend is configured as follows:

```
[HttpGet("/Products/latest")]
public async Task<NoContentResult> list()
{
  return NoContent();
}
```

In frontend using:

```
public getFromAPI() {
  return this.httpClient.get('/Products/latest', { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
    switchMap(res => res.status === 204 ? of([]) : of(res))
  ).subscribe();
}
```

And the response clearly contains a status despite not having a body:

[image]

Your problem might lie in `this.masterService` which seems to be proxying your http client and swallows some properties?