# How do I return NotFound() for an enumerable type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to return NotFound for this method but getting this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NotFoundResult' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<myapp.WeatherForecast>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I don't understand how it should be cast. I want to return a 404 if param is equal to "1".

```
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Test(int param)
{
    var rng = new Random();

    if (param == 1)
    {
        // Trying to return NotFound here
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}
```

### Update

I just had to do this:
`public ActionResult<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> Test(int param)`

Maybe I should close this but now I'm still confused about what impact this has. Before I was just returning an enumerable and now (if param doesn't == 1) I would be returning an Enumerable wrapped in an actionresult?

Comment: Try to use `ActionResult`, like `ActionResult<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>` or just `IActionResult`

Comment: To be honest: you should not return not found for collection. You'd better return empty collection. Not found is intended e.g. when there is no user with id=1 when you call /user/1 and endpoint return exactly one user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366730/proper-rest-response-for-empty-table

Comment: The answers are very valid. But just to emphasise - NotFound() is an HTTP status code 404 response. This is something you'd return to a HTTP request originally made to that particular controller. NotFound(), OK() or BadRequest() etc are all status coodes and can't be used in a model as the model isn't being hit by an HTTP request from a browser via the internet. The model is used by the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>` to `IActionResult` so that you can return NotFound,

```
public IActionResult Test(int param)
```

or for type safety

```
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>
```

---

**EDIT:**

> ASP.NET Core offers the following options for web API controller
> action return types:
>
> ```
>  - Specific type 
>  - IActionResult 
>  - ActionResult<T>
> ```

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1) explains when it's most appropriate to use each return type.

Comment: ahh so the first one is implicit then? I added a comment to my question about my confusion. I also get `The non-generic type 'IActionResult' cannot be used with type arguments` when using `IActionResult` like that instead of `ActionResult`

Comment: IF you return IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> object, It is implicitly converted to IActionResult. NotFound() is an ActionResult as well.

Comment: Why is it that I can cast to `ActionResult<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>` but not `IActionResult<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>` ? I get that error `The non-generic type 'IActionResult' cannot be used with type arguments`

Comment: sorry for typo. You need to use ActioResult<T> if you want to return specific Type

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You return `NotFound()` from a controller action, Razor Page `OnGet()`, or anyplace else you need to return an `IActionResult`, to indicate that the request should return a 404 not found error.