# should API return 404 status for api/object?filter=param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grape-api

Which HTTP status must be returned for api/object?filter=param if record not found?
I see following variants:

- return 404
- return 200 and blank response, for example {}

I don not find conventions for ruby community.
What is best practice?

Answer (score 3):

You can go in the deep here: [Proper REST response for empty table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366730/proper-rest-response-for-empty-table)

I think is correct to replay 200 with an empty object if you are calling an 'index' endpoint with search params

- request: `users?age=18`
- response:  code 200, body{}

But if you are calling a 'show' endpoint you should return 404

- request: `users/1`
- response: code 404