# REST API response status sode

Tags: rest

I'm fetching todos, if database has todos I return 200 status code, but if database has no todo then which status code should I return?

```php
if(!todos->isEmpty()){
    return response()->json(['todos' => $todos], 200);
}
else{
    return response()->json(['todos' => 'No Todos'], 404);
    // OR
    //return response()->json(['todos' => NULL], 404);
    // OR
    //return response()->json(['todos' => NULL], 200);
    // OR
    //return response()->json(['todos' => array()], 404);
    // OR
    //return response()->json(['todos' => array()], 200);
}
```

Comment: Please Reff this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746894/what-is-the-proper-rest-response-code-for-a-valid-request-but-an-empty-data

Comment: Empty array, 200 OK. The request works just fine and the endpoint exists. Also I think this means you can get rid of the `if` entirely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper REST response code for a valid request but an empty data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746894/what-is-the-proper-rest-response-code-for-a-valid-request-but-an-empty-data)