# Web forms: Return http status for no result found for paginated url?

Tags: asp.net, http, webforms, response, http-status-codes

We have a paginated URL like:

```
example.aspx/?pn=1
example.aspx/?pn=2
example.aspx/?pn=3
...
```

and so on.

This is web form URL that returns list of products. What should be returned back to the browser when we don't have any product for that request?

Should we return back like:

```
1. Response.StatusCode = 400; //Bad request
   Response.End();

 2. Response.StatusCode = 204; //No Content
    Response.End();
```

And should we use Respose.End() here? What is the correct way to inform client/crawlers that we don't have content on this page.

Comment: I would have thought this is an example for when a 404 is appropriate - especially given that content could become available at that URL later on (for example, when more products are added to the catalogue)

Comment: As stated by Rowland, 404 (Not Found) would be the appropriate response.  [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746894/what-is-the-proper-rest-response-code-for-a-valid-request-but-an-empty-data) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let us  Assume the Products are returned as a JSON array, so obvious respnse to that one would be 200 with an Empty array .

Returning `404 response` that the resource doesn't exist, kind of saying that it isn't even possible to ask for the products for this particular user. But in reality , it's possible to successfully return the list of products , it's just that product list is empty . This is completely in contrast to retrieval of one specific Product using an ID that doesn't exist in such Situations a `404` is correct.

While with `204` it at least tell your user that the request was successful and it had no content. In other terms The Resource `DOES` exist but for some reason  but the server chosen not to include it in its body .

A `204` can also be used as a response to a `POST` request where some action was carried out by the server without necessarily creating any new resource (which would have implied a `201` `CREATED`), or where it's for some other reason not relevant to return any resource.

Comment: "This is completely in contrast to retrieval of one specific Product using an ID that doesn't exist in such Situations a 404 is correct".. But specific ID if currently not present, may be a valid ID tomorrow.. take for example incremental IDs have been generated till value 100 and someone asks for 105 OR if ID was generated and record was later deleted but client asks for it

Comment: @maverick , if i consider your example in your comment that some one ask for the deleted record , i would consider to send it as  `404` , why because from [RFC2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.2.5) it clearly says `an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address`  so we use  `404`  when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.

Comment: What about incremental Id..something that might come in the future

Comment: @maverick `404` would be better choice , other option is sending `401` which i don't prefer because You don't want a hacker finding out which IDs are worth something by analyzing which ones returned which error code