# Should a POST request with a query return a 404?

Tags: rest, http, http-verbs

I've got an API that should return a single resource, but the method of specifying the resource is complex enough that shoehorning it into a `GET` request query string doesn't make sense, so instead we use a `POST` and have a representation of the query in the body.

Given the resource is just `/resource/search`, with no parameters, what should the response be if the specified resource is not found? If the result was an array, a `200` with an empty array body would be fine, and if the resource was specified in the URL then a `404` would make sense, but I'm not sure if the resource being specified in the body means a `400` or similar is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper REST response code for a valid request but an empty data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746894/what-is-the-proper-rest-response-code-for-a-valid-request-but-an-empty-data)

Answer (score 0):

I think when he specified resource is not found then return 404, it mean data not found by specified of REST.
When response status=200, body=[]||{} means that is found a empty value
Good luck!