# Bottle app with mongo db

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, pymongo, bottle

I am trying a general REST API with the help of Bottle and Mongo Database.

The error that I am getting on the web page on address 127.0.0.1:8010/ is

> Error: 404 Not Found
>
> Sorry, the requested URL http ://127.0.0.1:8010/ caused an error:
>
> Not found: '/'

In command line, I am getting this:

```
$ python myrestapi.py

Bottle v0.12.10 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on "http://127.0.0.1:8010/"
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016 01:54:46] GET / HTTP/1.1 404 720
```

Here  is my code for documents/myrestapi.py :

```
import json
import bottle

from bottle import route, run, request, abort
from pymongo import Connection

connection = Connection('localhost', 27017)
db = connection.mydatabase
app = bottle.Bottle()

@app.route('/documents', method='PUT')
def put_document():
  data = request.body.readline()

  if not data:
   abort(400, 'No data received')
   entity = json.loads(data)

  if not entity.has_key('_id'):
   abort(400, 'No _id specified')

try:
  db['documents'].save(entity)

  except ValidationError as ve:

  abort(400, str(ve))

@app.route('/documents/:id', method='GET')
def get_document(id):
entity = db['documents'].find_one({'_id':id})
if not entity:
    abort(404, 'No document with id %s' % id)
return entity

bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8010)
```

Comment: I have fixed the vertical spacing, but please fix the indentation of the Python code

Comment: Also, you have no route set at `/`, so have you tried `/documents/1`, or whatever ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error: 404 Not Found

404 error is thrown when an restful api which we look for is not available.

In this case if you have tried `/documents` or `/documents/1` then you will get a response, since you have `@app.route('/documents', method='PUT')` and `@app.route('/documents/:id', method='GET')`

For more information please refer

http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

[REST API 404: Bad URI, or Missing Resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930695/rest-api-404-bad-uri-or-missing-resource)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is helpful.