# Decorator to return a 404 in a Nest controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I'm working on a backend using NestJS, (which is amazing btw). I have a 'standard get a single instance of an entity situation' similar to this example below.

```
@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
    constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}
    ..
    ..
    ..
    @Get(':id')
    async findOneById(@Param() params): Promise<User> {
        return userService.findOneById(params.id);
    }
```

This is incredibly simple and works - however, if the user does not exist, the service returns undefined and the controller returns a 200 status code and an empty response.

In order to make the controller return a 404, I came up with the following:

```
    @Get(':id')
    async findOneById(@Res() res, @Param() params): Promise<User> {
        const user: User = await this.userService.findOneById(params.id);
        if (user === undefined) {
            res.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).send();
        }
        else {
            res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(user).send();
        }
    }
    ..
    ..
```

This works, but is a lot more code-y (yes it can be refactored).

This could really use a decorator to handle this situation:

```
    @Get(':id')
    @OnUndefined(404)
    async findOneById(@Param() params): Promise<User> {
        return userService.findOneById(params.id);
    }
```

Anyone aware of a decorator that does this, or a better solution than the one above?

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters this should be what you're looking for

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The shortest way to do this would be

```
@Get(':id')
async findOneById(@Param() params): Promise<User> {
    const user: User = await this.userService.findOneById(params.id);
    if (user === undefined) {
        throw new BadRequestException('Invalid user');
    }
    return user;
}
```

There is no point in decorator here because it would have the same code.

**Note:** `BadRequestException` is imported from `@nestjs/common`;

**Edit**

After some time with, I came with another solution, which is a decorator in the DTO:

```
import { registerDecorator, ValidationArguments, ValidationOptions, ValidatorConstraint } from 'class-validator';
import { createQueryBuilder } from 'typeorm';

@ValidatorConstraint({ async: true })
export class IsValidIdConstraint {

    validate(id: number, args: ValidationArguments) {
        const tableName = args.constraints[0];
        return createQueryBuilder(tableName)
            .where({ id })
            .getOne()
            .then(record => {
                return record ? true : false;
            });
    }
}

export function IsValidId(tableName: string, validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
    return (object, propertyName: string) => {
        registerDecorator({
            target: object.constructor,
            propertyName,
            options: validationOptions,
            constraints: [tableName],
            validator: IsValidIdConstraint,
        });
    };
}
```

Then in your DTO:

```
export class GetUserParams {
    @IsValidId('user', { message: 'Invalid User' })
    id: number;
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: it's definitely is point for such decorator, because it's quite routine code, and it is good practice to be less repetitive. furthermore it is much readable with decorator.

Comment: You can also throw just `BadRequestException`.

Comment: Why is everyone throwing `BadRequestException` when this is clearly `NotFoundException`? Bad request is for malformed request object. If you need to check the database, it's not a bad request issue.

Answer (score 17):

There is no built-in decorator for this, but you can create an [interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) that checks the return value and throws a `NotFoundException` on `undefined`:

### Interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class NotFoundInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle()
      .pipe(tap(data => {
        if (data === undefined) throw new NotFoundException();
      }));
  }
}
```

Then you can use the `Interceptor` by adding it to either a single endpoint:

```
@Get(':id')
@UseInterceptors(NotFoundInterceptor)
findUserById(@Param() params): Promise<User> {
    return this.userService.findOneById(params.id);
}
```

or all endpoints of your `Controller`:

```
@Controller('user')
@UseInterceptors(NotFoundInterceptor)
export class UserController {
```

### Dynamic Interceptor

You can also pass values to your interceptor to customize its behavior per endpoint.

Pass the parameters in the constructor:

```
@Injectable()
export class NotFoundInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private errorMessage: string) {}
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, stream$: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    return stream$
      .pipe(tap(data => {
        if (data === undefined) throw new NotFoundException(this.errorMessage);
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      }));
  }
}
```

and then create the interceptor with `new`:

```
@Get(':id')
@UseInterceptors(new NotFoundInterceptor('No user found for given userId'))
findUserById(@Param() params): Promise<User> {
    return this.userService.findOneById(params.id);
}
```

Comment: I believe this (and the addition by Maxime lower down) is a much more elegant solution to the accepted answer

Comment: Why you throw a 404?? This is for missing web server resources (Broken links). Read the documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404

Comment: @teteArg This is incorrect. The HTTP spec is very broad and does not define what a resource is. When you call `/users/49` and there is no user (resource) with the requested id 49, it is appropriate to respond with a 404 - the resource was not found. However, it is up to your API design, an empty 200 response might also make sense. Also see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9946520/4694994

Answer (score 8):

Updated version of the [@Kim Kern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51918372/2724204) for latests Nestjs versions:

As said [on the Nestjs docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide#interceptors):

> The interceptors API has also been simplified. In addition, the change was required due to this [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1016) which was reported by the community.

Updated code:

```js
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, NotFoundException, CallHandler } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class NotFoundInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private errorMessage: string) { }

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, stream$: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return stream$
      .handle()
      .pipe(tap(data => {
        if (data === undefined) { throw new NotFoundException(this.errorMessage); }
      }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If it's a simple case, I usually do it this lazy way without adding extra fluff:

```
import {NotFoundException} from '@nestjs/common'
...
@Get(':id')
async findOneById(@Param() params): Promise<User> {
    const user: User = await this.userService.findOneById(params.id)
    if (!user) throw new NotFoundException('User Not Found')
    return user
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use following to send your desired response in conjunction with correct status codes inside the header.

Inside your route handler in the controller class:

```
this.whateverService.getYourEntity(
  params.id
)
.then(result => {
  return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(result)
})
.catch(err => {
  return res.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).json(err)
})
```

For that to work you have to **reject** the Promise inside your service method like following:

```
const entity = await this.otherService
  .getEntityById(id)

if (!entity) {
  return Promise.reject({
    statusCode: 404,
    message: 'Entity not found'
  })
} 

return Promise.resolve(entity)
```

Here I just used another service inside the service class. You could of course just directly fetch your database or do whatever is needed to get your entity.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const OnUndefined = (
  Error: new () => HttpException = NotFoundException,
) => {
  return (
    _target: unknown,
    _propKey: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
  ) => {
    const original = descriptor.value;
    const mayThrow = (r: unknown) => {
      if (undefined === r) throw new Error();
      return r;
    };
    descriptor.value = function (...args: unknown[]) {
      const r = Reflect.apply(original, this, args);
      if ('function' === typeof r?.then) return r.then(mayThrow);
      return mayThrow(r);
    };
  };
};
```

Then use like this

```
@Get(':id')
@OnUndefined()
async findOneById(@Param() params): Promise<User> {
    return userService.findOneById(params.id);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more explanation on what the code does and how it will help the OP?

Answer (score 0):

The OnUndefined function create e decorator that must be used as decribed above.

If the service return a undefined response (the searched id not exist) the controller return a 404 (NotFoundException) or any other excepion passed as parameter to the @OnUndefined decorator

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I guess is to edit your UserService that way:

```
findOneById(id): Promise<User> {
  return new Promise<User>((resolve, reject) => {
    const user: User = await this.userService.findOneById(id);
    user ? 
      resolve(user) :
      reject(new NotFoundException())        
    }
}
```

No changes are needed on your controller.

Regards