# What's the difference between Interceptor vs Middleware vs Filter in Nest.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

What's the difference between an Interceptor, Filter and Middleware in Nest.js framework? When should one of them be used and favored over the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 246, accepted):

As you already implied with your question, all three are very similar concepts and in a lot of cases it is hard to decide and comes down to your preferences. But I can give an overview of the differences:

## [Interceptors](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors)

Interceptors have access to response/request before *and* after the route handler is called.

#### Registration

- Directly in the controller class with  `@UseInterceptors()` controller- or method-scoped
- Globally with `app.useGlobalInterceptors()` in `main.ts`

#### Examples

- LoggingInterceptor: Request before route handler and afterwards its result. Meassure time it takes.
- ResultMapping: Transform `null` to `[]` or wrap result in a response object: `users` -> `{users: users}`

#### Conclusion

I like that the registration is closer to the route handlers compared to middleware. But there are some limitations, for example, you cannot set the response code or alter the response with Interceptors when you send the `response` with the library-specific `@Res()` object in your route handler, see [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#appendix-library-specific-approach).

## [Middleware](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware)

Middleware is called only before the route handler is called. You have access to the response object, but you don't have the result of the route handler. They are basically express middleware functions.

#### Registration

- In the module, very flexible way of choosing relevant routes (with wildcards, by method,...)
- Globally with `app.use()` in `main.ts`

#### Examples

- FrontendMiddleware: redirect all routes except API to `index.html`, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54840961/4694994)
- You can use any express middleware that is out there. There are *lots* of libraries, e.g. [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) or [`morgan`](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan)

#### Conclusion

The registration of middleware is very flexible, for example: apply to all routes but one etc. But since they are registered in the module, you might not realize it applies to your controller when you're looking at its methods. It's also great that you can make use of all the express middleware libraries that are out there.

## [Exception Filters](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters)

Exception Filters are called after the route handler and after the interceptors. They are the last place to make changes before a response goes out.

#### Registration

- Directly in the controller class with  `@UseFilters()` controller- or method-scoped
- Globally `app.useGlobalFilters()` in your `main.ts`

#### Examples

- UnauthorizedFilter: Map to an easy to understand message for the user
- NotFoundFilter: Map all routes that are not found (not part of your api) to your `index.html`.

#### Conclusion

The basic use case for exception filters are giving understandable error messages (hiding technical details). But there are also other creative ways of usage: When you serve a single page application, then typically all routes should redirect to `index.html` except the routes of your API. Here, you can redirect on a `NotFoundException`. Some might find this clever others hacky. Your choice. ;-)

---

So the execution order is:

Middleware -> Interceptors -> Route Handler -> Interceptors -> Exception Filter (if exception is thrown)

With all three of them, you can inject other dependencies (like services,...) in their constructor.

Comment: Thanks @Kim for the detailed illustration. Can you share an example of using "ResultMapping"?

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful. :-) Have a look at this post. Here, the result is mapped to an exception. You just have to replace `tap(...)` by `map(data => ({response: data})` and you have mapped whatever data to a nested object. Does that answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51918372/4694994

Comment: one more question. You mentioned that i can use any middleware for nodejs and express in nestjs. Do you have an example of that? Thanks

Comment: Just add the middleware function in your `main.ts` with `app.use()`, e.g. `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: There are also Guards which are executed after each middleware, but before any interceptor or pipe.

Comment: You mentioned, `you cannot use Interceptors when you use the response with @Res() objects in your route handler.`, just checked with nest js version `6.12.6`, I am able to call the interceptor, was that an older version?

Comment: @pravindot17 Interceptors are called twice: Once before the controller and once after it. When you send the response with `@Res`, the interceptor won't be called after the controller; the same goes for ExceptionFilters. I will edit the answer to make it more clear, thanks for the hint. :-)

Comment: @KimKern thanks, but I did two checks one with @Res() and other without it, in both cases the interceptor got called.

Comment: @pravindot17 When you do `res.send()` the response is immediately sent out. Logically, the interceptor cannot alter the response after it was sent. Please have a look at the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#appendix-library-specific-approach): "The main disadvantages are that you lose compatibility with Nest features that depend on Nest standard response handling, such as Interceptors and the @HttpCode() decorator."

Comment: It's perfect! What about pipes?

Answer (score 156):

For those of us who "get it" better visually, I've created this NestJs pipeline digram based on the latest `v6.10` version. Please feel free to point out any inaccuracies. I'll review and update it promptly, if needed.

[image]

Comment: This is very useful.

Comment: I wonder if this image represents 2022?

Comment: @buryo it does.

Answer (score 12):

I'm assuming that you mean Pipes instead of Filters as Filters are primarily tied to Exception Handling.

There is definitely some overlap as Middleware are a flexible way of composing any web application but are more of a generic concept (creating a stack of functions to build a pipeline). The others are Nest specific concepts and as such tie in a bit more naturally with things like Dependency Injection.

Pipes are used to transform input data (and optionally to do validation).

Interceptors are really neat because they can transform both data coming in and leaving your API. They give you the ability to mutate what the original handler would have returned through the use of observable streams. This is something that you would probably need to implement using two middlewares (on either side of the handler).

Use Pipes when you want to transform data coming in to a handler.

Use Interceptors when bi-directional transformation is required.

Use middlewares when you want to stick closer to the traditional (eg Express) way of building your web app or when you want to more broadly apply functionality to many handlers at once (there's less decorators floating around in your code).

Answer (score -1):

#### Middleware

The usage and function of the middleware of Nest.js is basically equivalent to Express.js, which generally functions for:

- execute any code.
- make changes to the request and the response objects.
- end the request-response cycle.
- call the next middleware function in the stack.
- if the current middleware function does not end the request-response
  cycle, it must call `next()` to pass control to the next middleware
  function. Otherwise, the request will be left hanging.

#### Interceptor

The interceptor can transform data between the controller and the client-side, which can perform functions for:

- bind extra logic before / after method execution
- transform the result returned from a function
- transform the exception thrown from a function
- extend the basic function behavior
- completely override a function depending on specific conditions
  (e.g., for caching purposes)

#### Filter

In Nest.js, the Filter generally refers to the Exception filter, which is responsible for processing all unhandled exceptions across an application:

- a built-in global exception filter handles exceptions of type HttpException (and subclasses of it)
- custom exception filters are designed for controlling the exact flow of control and the content of the response sent back to the client. For example, add logging or use a different JSON schema based on some dynamic factors.