# How to perform RESTful request through rest proxy in Sencha Touch2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'd like to perform a RESTful get request like

```
"/commments/123" <br/>
```

but it always request addtional parameters like this

```
:<br/>
" _dc=1337095865783&page=1&start=0&limit=25" <br/>
```

Please tell me how to convert the addtional parameters to RESTful request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove extra parameters being added by Sencha automatically by setting any of the xxxParam options to false on the proxy object (limitParam, enablePagingParams, startParam, etc) and also disable the _dc cache querystring with noCache:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: '/comments',
    noCache: false,
    limitParam: false,
    enablePagingParams: false,
    startParam: false
}
```

If you're following the model/store structure of Sencha, then you can just make a rest proxy for your store and tell it to include the id (which it does by default):

```
new Ext.data.Store({
    model: "comments",
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: '/comments',
        appendId: true, //default
        noCache: false,
        limitParam: false,
        enablePagingParams: false,
        startParam: false
    }
});

// Collection url: /comments
// Instance url  : /comments/123
```

Lastly, you can use the buildUrl method on the proxy to create a custom Url format for the request.

Reference http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest for more details.

Comment: how to add limitParam as a RESTful parameter rather than "?limit=25" ?

Comment: Can you give me an example of a RESTful URL you need?

Something like /comments/limit/25?

Comment: I just don't know to to define the RESTful URL~~ , is your example RESTful， or the mixed is also acceptable?

Comment: You can use a querystring in a RESTful URL setting, but it doesn't follow the strict definition of correct use.  Can you give me a concrete example of what you're trying to do?

Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821663/querystring-in-rest-resource-url for RESTful best practice in reference to querystring.

Comment: Thank you, I have a better understand about RESTful API

Comment: Then , how to convert it to /comments/limit/25?