# Does serializing form data for Ajax violate REST?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

If I have a REST API that accepts request like so,

`/myuri/controller/action/firstname/johnny/lastname/quest`

and I have a form that via Ajax posts to the backend PHP page, how can I submit my form's information without violating REST?

If I use `.serialize` for my form or use post like so,

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.post( "test.php", $( "#testform" ).serialize() );
```

or,

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

isn't that keeping me from the format of my URI in the REST fashion, so my `Ajax` function has the `url` property looking like a REST URI?

How do I keep my URI in the REST fashion and be able to send data from a form to the backend pages?

EDIT:  Are my assumptions about what a REST URI should be wrong here?

[Querystring in REST Resource url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821663/querystring-in-rest-resource-url)

Comment: Use `$.get` so the parameters will be put in the URL, and then use a rewrite rule that translates query parameters into URL components.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks.  I seem to be going round and round on this because some REST I see with a querystring, some do not, and it looks like the data: property of Ajax was made solely for the ?querystring in mind and that all the rewrites, are "hacky."  Am I reading too much into what REST URIs should look like?

Comment: I don't use REST much. This site seems to agree with your expectation about RESTful URIs: http://blog.2partsmagic.com/restful-uri-design/