# REST mappings to subresources

Tags: java, rest, model-view-controller

I have some trouble with understanding the perfect way to apply the REST pattern for objects and subobjects.
Let us consider following classes:

```
class Foo {
    Long id;
    Bar bar;
}

class Bar {
    Long id;
    String name;
}
```

As far as I understand in simple cases we have:

1. List of `Foo` objects - `.../foos`
2. One `Foo` object - `.../foos/{id}`

Now I have problem understanding how accesing subobjects will work. What will be correct if I want to fetch `Foo` objects, in which `Bar` objects has `name == baz`

Whether that will be `.../foos/bar/name/baz` or `/foos?barName=baz`?

Which mapping should I use to fetch `Bar` objects by parameter `name` out of `Foo`?. Would that will be `.../foos/bar/{name}` or something different?

Comment: Check the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821663/querystring-in-rest-resource-url

Comment: since it is not clear for me, can you provide answer for my particular case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main question is: which resource are you requesting? In your case, you want a list of `foos`, so the URI will be `/foos`, period. Remaining constraints must be set some other way.

Then, you want to filter the returned list so that only `foos` with a specific `bar` are retrieved. This could be done via a parameter: `/foos?barName=someName`.

Here are some common URLs:

1. `GET /foos`: list all `foos`
2. `GET /foos/{id}`: get specific `foo`
3. `GET /bars`: list all `bars`
4. `GET /bars/{id}`: get specific `bar`
5. `GET /foos/{id}/bars`: get all `bars` of specific `foo`
6. `GET /foos/{id}/bars/{id}`: get specific `bar` of specific `foo` (same as `GET /bars/{id}` but more restrictive)

Comment: `Then, you want to filter the returned list so that only foos with a specific bar are retrieved. This could be done via a parameter: /foos?barName=someName.` Since parameters are only of `Bar` type wouldn't it be better: `GET .../foos/bar?name=sample` ?